# How to populate dependant select menus dynamically using jQuery, PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, cascadingdropdown

I have searched quite a bit on here about this topic. But I could not find a solution for my problem. I'd appreciate it a lot if you could help me, this is for a school project I am working on.

I have a database with a table ("Main_table") and columns including "sector" and "sub_sector". I want to have two select boxes, first one will load all the records from database in "sector" column and the second one will load all the records from database in "sub_sector" column depending on the selection value of the first select box. (For example: If I select "plastics" on the first select box, then second select box should be updated with sub_sector values where sector value is equal to "plastics").

I have managed to load the options values from database for the first select box but when I click on any selection, it does not load any option to the second select box. You can find the codes below. I did not put "sector_options.php" below, as it seems to work just fine.

index.html shown below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 

$('#filter_sector')
.load('/php/sector_options.php'); //This part works fine - uploads options to the first select box

$('#filter_sector').change(function() {
$('#filter_subsector').load('/php/subsector_options.php?filter_sector=' + $("#filter_sector").val()
} //This part does not work - no options on the second select box
);
});

</script>

<body>
<div id="sectors"><p>Sector:</p>
<select id="filter_sector" name="select_sector" multiple="multiple" size="5"> </select>    
</div> 

<div id="subsectors"><p>Sub Sector:</p>
<select id="filter_subsector" name="select_subsector" multiple="multiple" size="5"> <option value="" data-filter-type="" selected="selected">
-- Make a choice --</option>
</select> 
</div>      

</body>
</html>
```

sector_options.php shown below:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("*******", "*******","******","********") or die (mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT sector FROM Main_table ";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$options .= "<option value=\"".$row['sector']."\">".$row['sector']."</option>\n  ";
}

echo $options;

?>
```

subsector_options.php shown below:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("********", "*****,"*******", "********") or die (mysql_error());

$Sectors = $_REQUEST['filter_sector'];

$query = "SELECT sub_sector FROM Main_table WHERE sector='$Sectors'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {$options .= "<option value=\"".$row['sub_sector']."\">".$row['sub_sector']."</option>\n  ";
}

echo $options;

?>
```

Comment: You can certainly do it this way, but for a small set of values it is much easier to use a nested menu. Have a look at [`optgroup`](http://html5doctor.com/element-index/#optgroup) - I think this feature is underused, personally.

Comment: Yikes! Your AJAX scripts have SQL injection bugs. If you continue to do things that way, have a look at `mysqli_real_escape_string`, or - better still - use parameterisation.

Comment: Sorry I have not used Ajax before, so I can not see where I am doing wrong. The codes above works fine for the first select box but not for the second select box. Is there any line up there which I should delete/add/correct? Thanks for your help,

Comment: An optgroup is not appropriate? It is _significantly_ simpler, and does away for the need for AJAX entirely.

Comment: Never used optgroup before. Can I load the options from the database using optgroup? Because I will need to load the options from the database eventually.

Comment: Indeed, yes; [here's what they look like](http://htmldog.com/examples/select2.html). This may not be suitable for you if you have hundreds of sectors, each having hundreds of sub-sectors, since the resulting menu will be slow to load. But if you have a few hundred options + sub-options, it will make your life easier.

Comment: I will sure have a look at it now. Do you know why the codes above do not yield any options for the second select box though? It works for the first select box, but nothing comes up for the second select box.

Comment: It's difficult to say without access to a real-time AJAX monitor. You'll have one in your browser, usually labelled as "Developer tools". Or Firefox/Firebug is a good combo. Open this tool and run your AJAX operation, and see if it gets the input parameters you expect, and see if it returns the correct HTTP status code (200).

Comment: Do you think .load() method is suitable for this? I have seen in many examples they use $.get or $.ajax or $.getJSON. Also, I have created one table with many rows in database. Do you think this is why it does not work? Should I seperate it to two tables maybe? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If `load()` works for the first one, then yes! To find out what's wrong, use the AJAX monitor - it will take you a couple of minutes to try that. Also, check your browser console for JavaScript errors.

Comment: Pleased it works. It's not quite right though - you are replying with a whole HTML document in each case, whereas you _only_ need the contents of the select menu in each case, which `load` will inject for you inside the appropriate menu. That is to say the response you see in your AJAX monitor should only contain `<option>...</option>` lines (as many as are required in each case).

Comment: Yeah I can see it in the AJAX monitor. Do you have any advice for correcting this? Should I fix my .php file or something else?

Comment: Do you have that HTML in your options PHP files? If not, your free host is probably adding it. If you reckon they are, try adding `header('Content-type: application/json');` as the first line in each case.

Comment: It seems like PHP files echo only `<options>...</options>` . Could you tell me where do I need to add `header('Content-type: application/json');` exactly and in .html or .php? Also, I am using .load() method to fetch data, so do you think using json content-type would not be suitable? Sorry if I sound dull, I really don't have much understanding with this AJAX thing.

Comment: Oh now I found out that all my PHP files start with Doctype, html and all that. I should remove all of them and PHP files should include only `<?php.......?>` part yeah? Crazy stuff.

Comment: Yes, edit the options files so they only render options lines (of course you need all the doctype and HTML stuff in your index script). Don't forget you can call options files directly in a browser tab, and then View Source to see what they have generated.

Comment: Thanks mate, you have been great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, the solutions were:

- Check how AJAX operations are doing using a browser network monitor
- Load AJAX fetcher scripts in a browser tag - in many cases they will render quite happily there, allowing them to be more easily debugged
- AJAX scripts that return HTML for injection should *only* return that HTML, and not a full HTML document.